# resolve Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger from .NET Core class lib via AspNetCore WebApp utilizing Serilog.AspNetCore and AutofacSerilogIntegration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac, serilog

I am getting the following exception:

> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger'

["At the moment (9/28/18), Serilog.AspNetCore doesn't get involved in DI/OoC configuration"](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/58)

Is it possible to register `Serilog.Core.Logger` as an implementation of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` within an Autofac DI container for resolution within .NET Core class libraries?

Here is my current implementation:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            //.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogConnection"), "_logs", columnOptions: columnOptions)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            //.WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents("<YOUR_APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_KEY>")
            .CreateLogger();
        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");

            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
            host.Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog();
}

public class Startup
{
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        _builder.Register<ILogger>((c, p) =>
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
              .WriteTo.RollingFile(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString() + "/Log-{Date}.txt")
              .CreateLogger();
        }).SingleInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried resolving an `ILogger<T>` instead of a plain `ILogger`?

Comment: ILogger<T> is exactly what I was looking for. I also removed builder.Register<ILogger> from startup.ConfigureServices. If you re-post your response as an answer, I will accept that and this question can be closed. Thanks for your help as well as your awesome blog articles and OS libraries!!!

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try resolving `ILogger<T>` instead of `ILogger`. The default logging factory only registers the generic version.